# How do I order a group by clause in sql

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I want to select from my FileList all different files using group by. But I want to get Back only the elements with the highest id. I only get the first entry back. 
How to fix this?

```
select * from files group by name;
```

This is my table-content...

```
 ID      NAME          DATE               USER 
1443 - /test.txt - 24 May 2013 12:56:15 - XX
1444 - /test.txt - 24 May 2013 12:54:41 - XX
1445 - /test.txt - 24 May 2013 12:53:38 - AB
1446 - /test.txt - 24 May 2013 12:44:32 - XX
1983 - /asdf.txt - 24 May 2013 13:46:32 - KS
```

Comment: That's not how `group by` works. Read this to understand what is going on: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from files 
where id in
(
  select max(id)
  from files
  group by name
)
```

or

```
select f.* 
from files f
inner join 
(
  select max(id) as id
  from files
  group by name
) x on x.id = f.id
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c25eb/1)

Comment: I don't think this syntax would be valid on an ANSI standard platform..

Comment: Really? Why? I can't see the problem.

Comment: ANSI SQL requires that the select-list include the column(s) in the GROUP BY clause.  So you would write the subquery: `(select name, max(id) as id from files group by name)` and that would be okay.

Comment: Nope, [I'm wrong](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5aa5e/1). For some reason I thought that column in the `GROUP BY` must be in the column list.

Comment: Yeah, MySQL is more permissive than strict ANSI SQL.  MySQL lets you write some forms of ambiguous statements when using GROUP BY, and trusts you know what you're doing.  :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin This still shouldn't work in MSSQL. Looks like this is valid.

Comment: Aha - I'm wrong about this.  You can have a select-list without the grouping column.  Here's a reference on GROUP BY rules based on "SQL-99 Complete, Really":  https://kb.askmonty.org/en/rules-for-grouping-columns/  But you can't have a select-list with non-grouping column unless it's inside a grouping function.  E.g. `select a, b, max(c) from table group by a` makes b ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:-

```
select *,max(id) from files group by name;
```

Comment: I guess it was downvoted because the usage of the group by is incorrect (just like in the original question) - even though it's accepted by MySQL in the standard configuration, see here: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: Incorrect ? How ?? You mean i should have included 'name' in the select list ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Read the link from my comment.